# sloppy matching of hash keys?

Tags: perl, hash, key

I'm currently comparing two lists of genes with the aim of finding overlapping genes between two lists.

At the moment, I store the names of the gene as a hash key for for both lists (blast1 and blast2) and find keys (genes) that exist in both hashes:

Input 1:

```
XLOC_000157_6.21019:12.8196,_Change:1.04564,_p:0.04915,_q:0.999592      99.66   gi|475392713|dbj|AB759708.1|_Xenopus_laevis_PhyHd_mRNA_for_phytanoyl-CoA_dioxygenase_like_protein,_complete_cds
XLOC_000159_636.025:343.104,_Change:-0.890436,_p:0.00575,_q:0.999592    99.47   gi|9909981|emb|AJ278067.1|_Xenopus_laevis_mRNA_for_putative_XIRG_protein
XLOC_000561_31.1018:14.9273,_Change:-1.05905,_p:0.0073,_q:0.999592      91.57   gi|165973401|ref|NM_001113689.1|_Xenopus_(Silurana)_tropicalis_cytokine_inducible_SH2-containing_protein_(cish),_mRNA
```

Assign for 1st gene list...

```
$input1 = $ARGV[0];
open my $blast1, '<', $input1 or die $!;

my $results1 = 0;
my (@blast1ID, @blast1_info, @percent_id, @split);
while (<$blast1>) {
    chomp;
    @split = split('\t');
    push @blast1_info, $split[0];
    push @percent_id, $split[1];
    push @blast1ID, $split[2];
    $results1++;
}   

print "$results1 blast hits in '$input1'\n";

push @{$blast1{$blast1ID[$_]} }, [ $blast1_info[$_], $percent_id[$_] ] for 0 .. $#blast1ID;
```

Input 2:

```
XLOC_000561_31.1018:14.9273,_Change:-1.05905,_p:0.0073,_q:0.999592      91.57   gi|165973401|ref|NM_001113689.1|_Xenopus_(Silurana)_tropicalis_cytokine_inducible_SH2-containing_protein_(cish),_mRNA
XLOC_000679_57.3461:29.2637,_Change:-0.970585,_p:0.03645,_q:0.999592    85.13   gi|51704135|gb|BC081195.1|_Xenopus_laevis_hypothetical_protein_LOC446937,_mRNA_(cDNA_clone_IMAGE:6640116),_partial_cds
XLOC_000766_10.699:6.33756,_Change:-0.755473,_p:0.0384,_q:0.999592      99.04   gi|195972824|ref|NM_001130940.1|_Xenopus_laevis_interleukin_6_signal_transducer_(gp130,_oncostatin_M_receptor)_(il6st),_mRNA
```

Assign for 2nd gene list

```
$input2 = $ARGV[1];
open my $blast2, '<', $input2 or die $!;

my $results2 = 0;
my (@blast2ID, @blast2_info, @percent_id);
while (<$blast2>) {
    chomp;
    @split = split('\t'); 
    push @blast2_info, $split[0];
    push @percent_id, $split[1];
    push @blast2ID, $split[2];
    $results2++;
}   
print "$results2 blast hits in '$input2'\n";

push @{$blast2{$blast2ID[$_]} }, [ $blast2_info[$_], $percent_id[$_] ] for 0 .. $#blast2ID;
```

Find keys (genes) that exist in both hashes:

```
my $intersect_count = 0;
for my $key (sort keys %blast1) {
    if (exists $blast1{$key} && $blast2{$key}) {
        $intersect_count++;
            for my $part1 (@ { $blast1{$key} } ) {
                ($hit1, $percent_id1) = @$part1;
            } 
            for my $part2 (@ { $blast2{$key} } ) {
                ($hit2, $percent_id2) = @$part2;
            }
    push @intersect, "$key\tC1:$hit1 [$percent_id1]\tC2:$hit2 [$percent_id2]\n";            
    push @intersecting_list, "$key";                
    }
}
```

The above code would find one gene that's present in both lists:

```
gi|165973401|ref|NM_001113689.1|_Xenopus_(Silurana)_tropicalis_cytokine_inducible_SH2-containing_protein_(cish),_mRNA
```

---

My question is how can I adapt this so that genes that have similar names are included in the output? for example I would want to see:

```
gi|186928837|ref|NM_005982.3|_Homo_sapiens_SIX_homeobox_1_(SIX1),_mRNA
```

find a match with:

```
gi|154142326|ref|NM_001100275.1|_Xenopus_(Silurana)_tropicalis_SIX_homeobox_1_(six1),_mRNA
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: How is `NM_005982.3` *like* `NM_001100275.1`? Do you want to match just the initial two characters?

Comment: No - that's the difficult thing - I'm trying to match on gene name - in that example `SIX_homeobox_1_(SIX1)` and `SIX_homeobox_1_(six1)`.

Comment: Well that would be fine if, say you want to match the *end* of the gene name case-independently. Is there something like the last *four* fields (separated on underscores) that is always the part that must match? You have to define "similar" in some way.

Answer (score 2):

There are two strategies you can use

1. Extract the actual key you want to use, which is then matched exactly.

   Some parts of the original key may no be of any use to you – remove them. Depending on the input, you may also want to do Unicode normalization, and perform case folding.

   In your case, a common key for

   ```
   gi|186928837|ref|NM_005982.3|_Homo_sapiens_SIX_homeobox_1_(SIX1),_mRNA
   gi|154142326|ref|NM_001100275.1|_Xenopus_(Silurana)_tropicalis_SIX_homeobox_1_(six1),_mRNA
   ```

   could look like

   ```
   gi|ref|nm_00|_six_homeobox_1_(six1),_mrna
   ```
2. Do away with hashes, and calculate a similarity index between all possible records. To get an idea for such indices, you may want to look at the [Levenstein edit distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenstein_distance). You can then treat all other records within certain bounds as a match. This is considerably more expensive, but may yield better results.

I do not know your problem domain, so I can't make any good suggestions.

---

There are some problems with you code, especially when finding hits. It looks like it should be equivalent to this:

```
my $intersect_count = 0;
for my $key (sort keys %blast1) {
    if (exists $blast2{$key}) {
        $intersect_count++;
        my ($hit1, $percent_id1) = @{ $blast1{$key}[-1] };
        my ($hit2, $percent_id2) = @{ $blast2{$key}[-1] };
        push @intersect, "$key\tC1:$hit1 [$percent_id1]\tC2:$hit2 [$percent_id2]\n";
        push @intersecting_list, $key;
    }
}
```

Differences:

1. `exists $blast1{$key} && $blast2{$key}` is parsed as `exists($blast1{$key}) && $blast2{$key}` and even that is silly, because we know that `$blast1{$key}` exists: we just fetched it via `keys`!
2. When looping over an array and assigning each item to a variable, the variable will retain the value of the last item. That is `my $y; for my $x (@xs) { $y = $x }` is equivalent to, but less efficient than, `my $y = $xs[-1]`.

Comment: This is a fantastic answer to what I feared was an impossible question. I'll definitely look into the Levenstein edit distance. Would you mind elaborating a little more on the edits you made in the key lookup?

Comment: @FlyingFrog I edited my answer with some explanations on my modifications. I do not suggest you actually use Levenstein distance. It is useful when smoothing over typos (or point mutations) etc. You will have to design your own metric, but Levenstein could be a part of it. The first step is to explicitly define for yourself when two keys compare equal.